# Networking with ios

Tags: java, iphone, networking

I have an application that was written in Java and runs on the users machine. I now want to build an application on the iPhone which will communicate with my java app.

Can somebody point me in the right direction on how I can send and receive TCP packets with the iPhone, I want to of course be able to do that using wifi and 3G.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [NSStream](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html) classes.  I've found it pretty easy to use.

See the [SimpleNetworkStreams](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleNetworkStreams/Introduction/Intro.html) for an example.

One problem I found is that the iphone sdk does not include the NSStream method getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream: which is what Mac OS examples use to open a NStream connection but there are lots of places that show you how to create your own like [here](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43551/1763).